# Cross origin request with SproutCore in IE9

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, sproutcore, cors

I am trying to build a web app based on SproutCore 1.8. To retrieve data from a server the app makes CORS requests to a REST web service running on a separate domain.

The code for this looks like the following:

```
var request = SC.Request.getUrl('http://example.com/some/path');
request.set('attachIdentifyingHeaders', NO);    
request.json().notify(this, this.didFetchData).send();
```

This works great in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 9. In fact, IE9 runs into a JavaScript error "Access Denied" in SproutCore's internal request implementation. The error is raised at this line:

```
// initiate request.
rawRequest.open(this.get('type'), this.get('address'), async);
```

After some short investigation I found out that Microsoft implemented a dedicated XDomainRequest object for CORS requests in IE9. This does not seem to be supported by SproutCore as I infer from these lines (SproutCore native request implementation selection):

```
return tryThese(
  function() { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
  function() { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); },
  function() { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }
);
```

Is this a shortcoming of SproutCore or am I missing something? If so, do you have any suggestions as to how I could work around the issue without writing my own request abstraction?

Note that CORS is a requirement of the existing server infrastructure I am working with. I can neither put the service on the same domain as the server delivering the client nor can I solve the problem with a reverse-proxy or similar infrastructure stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options

1)  Hack Sproutcore itself.  You could try adding

`function() {return new XDomainRequest(); }`

to that list of difference xhr conveyances.  Add it first; if it's available on the browser it will be used, otherwise the the code falls back to the other objects.

2)  If you don't want to modify the SC source, you can create your own `App.CorsResponse` class that extends `SC.XHRResponse`.  In your implementation, provide your own `createRequest` method and do what I said in 1).  Whenever you create a request, specify the `responseClass` to be your custom implementation.

Comment: OK thank you, this is pretty much what I was expecting. Option 1 came to my mind before, but I think this is the last thing I should be doing. I'll try with Option 2.

Comment: Turns out that both options boil down to the same result in the end. You have to override not only createRequest, but also invokeTransport and finishRequest. This doesn't even include error handling and means a lot of repeated code. I think the SC.Response class would need some more abstraction to make a clean solution possible. XDomainRequest does not have the same attributes and callbacks, e.g. you need to implement onload instead of onreadystatechange and you need to check for errors with different callbacks. I will post the code as soon as stackoverflow allows me to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

I have quickly coded a solution based on hvgotcodes' suggestion. The code below implements a subclass of `SC.XHRResponse` that adds the required functionality for handling IE-specific XDomainRequest CORS requests. Note that this does not handle errors in IE when using XDomainRequest yet.

```
MyApp.CorsRequest = SC.XHRResponse.extend({
  createRequest: function() {
    function tryThese() {
      for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        try {
          var item = arguments[i]();
          return item;
        } catch (e) {}
      }
      return NO;
    }

    return tryThese(
      function() { return new XDomainRequest(); },
      function() { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
      function() { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); },
      function() { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }
    );
  },

  invokeTransport: function() {
    var rawRequest, transport, handleReadyStateChange, async, headers;

    rawRequest = this.createRequest();
    this.set('rawRequest', rawRequest);

    // configure async callback - differs per browser...
    async = !!this.getPath('request.isAsynchronous');

    if (async) {
      if (!SC.browser.isIE && !SC.browser.isOpera) {
        SC.Event.add(rawRequest, 'readystatechange', this,
                     this.finishRequest, rawRequest);
      } else if(SC.browser.isIE) {
           transport = this;
        handleLoad = function() {
          if (!transport) { return null; }
          var ret = transport.finishRequest();
          if (ret) { transport = null; }
          return ret;
        };
        rawRequest.onload = handleLoad;          
      } else {
        transport = this;
        handleReadyStateChange = function() {
          if (!transport) { return null; }
          var ret = transport.finishRequest();
          if (ret) { transport = null; }
          return ret;
        };
        rawRequest.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;
      }
    }

    // initiate request.
    rawRequest.open(this.get('type'), this.get('address'), async);

    // now send the actual request body - for sync requests browser will
    // block here
    rawRequest.send(this.getPath('request.encodedBody')) ;
    if (!async) { this.finishRequest(); }

    return rawRequest;
  }, 

  finishRequest: function(evt) {
    var rawRequest = this.get('rawRequest'),
        readyState = rawRequest.readyState,
        error, status, msg;

       if (SC.browser.isIE) {
            readyState = 4;
            rawRequest.status = 200;
       }       

    if (readyState === 4 && !this.get('timedOut')) {
      this.receive(function(proceed) {
        if (!proceed) { return; }

        // collect the status and decide if we're in an error state or not
        status = -1;
        try {
          status = rawRequest.status || 0;
        } catch (e) {}

        // if there was an error - setup error and save it
        if ((status < 200) || (status >= 300)) {

          try {
            msg = rawRequest.statusText || '';
          } catch(e2) {
            msg = '';
          }

          error = SC.$error(msg || "HTTP Request failed", "Request", status);
          error.set("errorValue", this) ;
          this.set('isError', YES);
          this.set('errorObject', error);
        }

        // set the status - this will trigger changes on related properties
        this.set('status', status);
      }, this);

      // Avoid memory leaks
      if (!SC.browser.isIE && !SC.browser.isOpera) {
        SC.Event.remove(rawRequest, 'readystatechange', this, this.finishRequest);
      } else {
           if (window.XDomainRequest)
                rawRequest.onload = null;
           else
             rawRequest.onreadystatechange = null;
      }

      return YES;
    }
    return NO;
  } 
});
```